# combinatorial Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to check if the following is true for all $k$. Can anyone help me?

$$k{n\choose r} ={kn\choose kr} $$

I know that using the formula, I will obtain:

$$ k\left(\frac{n!}{r!(n-k)!}\right) = \frac{nk!}{(kr)!(nk-rk)!} $$

However, I do not think that is true. Do you think that if I assign values to $n$, $k$, and $r$ and prove that is not equal, showing a counterexample, it should be enough to prove that is not true for all $k$?

Thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott for that to be a counterexample you would want $6\neq 4=2\binom{2}{1}$, right?

Comment: @bburGsamohT: I misread the question in its original formatting.

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample is indeed enough to show it is not true for all $k$. Here is a hint for where to look for such a counterexample: $\binom{0}{0}=1$.

Comment: Can you explain it better please?

Comment: @user290335 What part?

Comment: I did not understand your counterexample

Comment: Are you saying that if n=r= 0, it is nor true for all k

Comment: There are multiple counterexamples that you can come up with. Please play around with it for a few minutes to see if you can come up with one. You thinking critically and finding the answer would be much better than me giving you one. All you need is a specific example where the proposed equality fails.

Comment: I did: n=10,r=9,k=2, using this values I will obtain that 10 is different than 190 so I found a counterexample. Do you think that is correct?

Comment: Yes, that works.